# Does Postgres log implicit transactions?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, logging, transactions

[Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/tutorial-transactions.html) state

> PostgreSQL actually treats every SQL statement as being executed within a transaction. If you do not issue a BEGIN command, then each individual statement has an implicit BEGIN and (if successful) COMMIT wrapped around it. A group of statements surrounded by BEGIN and COMMIT is sometimes called a transaction block.

`SELECT` statement logs aren't wrapped in `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` when I set `log_statement='all'` (as per [How to log PostgreSQL queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722221/how-to-log-postgresql-queries)). `INSERT` logs, on the other hand, are wrapped in `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`.

Are implicit transactions excluded from logs?

Related: [Does Postgresql implicitly wrap select statements in transaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65967896/does-postgresql-implicitly-wrap-select-statements-in-transaction)

Comment: "INSERT logs, on the other hand, are wrapped in BEGIN and COMMIT"  That must be something the client is doing.  INSERTs do implicitly run in a transaction of course, but the transaction markers do not get logged.  The client (or proxy) is implicitly sending BEGIN and COMMIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Postgres log implicit transactions?

No.

The logs show explicit SQL statements from clients. The implicit transactions around standalone statements weren't controlled by statements, so BEGIN and COMMIT don't turn up in the logs.

Comment: ... that is, unless you set `log_min_messages = debug5`.